# Set collection doesn't always enforce uniqueness with the Date datatype? Does the following example seem correct?

Tags: apex, datetime, date, set

Consider the following unit test:

```
@istest
public static void datetests2() {
    Set<Date> dts = new Set<Date>();
    dts.add(DateTime.now().Date());
    dts.add(DateTime.now().addHours(1).Date());
    dts.add(DateTime.now().addHours(2).Date());
    system.debug(dts);

    system.assertEquals(1, dts.size());
}
```

The result, as I'm sure you'd expect would be that the test would pass. The debug statement showing something like:

```
14:49:36:002 USER_DEBUG [22]|DEBUG|{2019-05-01 00:00:00}
```

Now consider this very similar unit test:

```
@istest
public static void datetests() {
    Set<Date> dts = new Set<Date>();
    dts.add(Date.valueOf(DateTime.now()));
    dts.add(Date.valueOf(DateTime.now().addHours(1)));
    dts.add(Date.valueOf(DateTime.now().addHours(2)));
    system.debug(dts);

    system.assertEquals(1, dts.size());
}
```

You would expect it to pass. Well, I did. But in fact, it fails.

```
14:57:10:001 FATAL_ERROR System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 1, Actual: 3
```

Displaying something like:

```
14:57:10:001 USER_DEBUG [10]|DEBUG|{2019-05-01 09:00:00, 2019-05-01 10:00:00, 2019-05-01 11:00:00}
```

Now, part of why this may be happening is clear - While logic suggests that Date.ValueOf returns a date, it actually seems to return a DateTime (which contradicts the docs, but whatever...)

In anonymous Apex:

```
system.debug(Date.ValueOf(DateTime.now()));
```

Returns at the moment:

```
15:00:24:002 USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|2019-05-01 10:00:00
```

which is a datetime

But you'd really expect Set to enforce uniqueness across dates regardless, right?

I've searched online, known issues, etc. and didn't find anything obvious. I confess this completely caught me by surprise.

So my question are:

1. Can you reproduce this?
2. Can anyone find/show documentation that addresses this?
3. Does anyone know if this has always been like this, or are we seeing a change in behavior?
4. Any other thoughts or ideas?

Note - this testing is on a fresh SFDX scratch org running Spring 19 API 45. I did run the unit tests at API 40 just to make sure it wasn't a version artifact.

Comment: As a matter of interest, even without the bug this unit test will fail when the time is between 22:00 and 00:00 (exclusive) when the test is executed.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**

It seems to have been reported as a [**known issue here**](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001RWw5QAG). Though the title says `String.valueOf` but the code sample in the details reflects what is being observed here.

---

This overall behavior is impacted because of `Date.valueOf` and not `Set`, as `Set` is behaving as expected. I think you will need to reach out to Salesforce Support (I will try to reach out as well) to report this behavior as the `Date.valueOf` should not return the timestamp values at the first place at least based on the documentation.

Details and explanation below as response to your questions.

---

> 1. Can you reproduce this?

Yes. I was able to reproduce the behavior you have mentioned here.

---

> 2. Can anyone find/show documentation that addresses this?

You may have (re)discovered a behavior (bug) here in the [`Date.valueOf`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm?search_text=date.valueof) method itself. There's a mention about the timestamp being returned in the docs (emphasis mine):

> In API version 33.0 or earlier, if you call `Date.valueOf` with an object that represents a `Datetime`, the method **returns a Date value that contains the hours, minutes, and seconds.**

It just seems with the latest API version, it is behaving just like versions prior to 33.0 (as far as I can confirm)

---

> 3. Does anyone know if this has always been like this, or are we seeing a change in behavior?

Based on the docs and the behavior, it seems this is a change in the expected behavior.

---

> 4. Any other thoughts or ideas?

The behavior for `Set` is as expected. In your second test, you are able to add the values in the `Set` as they are still distinct because of the timestamp that is returned along with. And if there are distinct values, your `Set` contains 3 different values in that case. This definitely needs to be reported.

Comment: Regarding the behavior of set being as expected - shouldn't the fact that the Set is declared as type Date (Set<Date>) enforce uniqueness based on the Date part of the value? Intuitively, that is what I would expect...

Comment: Ideally yes but I think because the *data* in the set is still unique, it works on the data itself. And that based on the docs prior to v34.0 and the known issue, because a `Date` could still contain the timestamp values, the `Set` itself seems to be acting upon the data it contains.